# drools camel server reponse empty result

Tags: drools

I have a strange problem need your kind assistance!

I have deployed the drools server 5.5.0 to my tomcat, and I can use the wrapped testing case without problem in the last week 
when I type `http://xxx:8080/camel-client/test.jsp`

then the response will be

```
Request: "Hello World" 
Response: "Hello World"
```

Today, I run it normally at first, but later I want to try to use the https so I change the url to

```
https://xxx:8443/camel-client/test.jsp
```

however the result is

```
Request: "Hello World" 
Response: ""
```

then I change back to use http, still have empty response

I have checked the log, there is execution result returned back:

```
19:23:56,018 TRACE InstrumentationProcessor:88 - to: Recording duration: 182 millis for exchange: Exchange[Message: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><execution-results><result identifier="message"><org.test.Message><text>echo:Hello World</text></org.test.Message></result><fact-handle identifier="message" external-form="0:2:1391417336:1391417336:2:DEFAULT"/></execution-results>]
```

but just the response is empty

```
19:23:56,019 TRACE AsyncProcessorHelper:82 - Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-46148-1384255363195-1-1 -> Exchange[Message: ]
```

Anybody can kindly check my problem? I have debug it for a whole day, but have not figure out this strange problem.

I even try to redeploy the drools camel server, but problem still there! I indeed can successfully run it in the last whole week. I didn't change any library and I believe https should not cause the problem too

below is the log for reference

```
19:23:56,015 TRACE CxfRsProducer:183 - Response body = org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl@26d6466f 
19:23:56,016 TRACE DefaultCxfRsBinding:195 - Populate external header Date=[Tue, 12 Nov 2013 11:23:55 GMT] as Date 
19:23:56,016 TRACE DefaultCxfRsBinding:195 - Populate external header Content-Length=[268] as Content-Length 
19:23:56,016 TRACE DefaultCxfRsBinding:195 - Populate external header Content-Type=[text/plain] as Content-Type 
19:23:56,016 TRACE DefaultCxfRsBinding:195 - Populate external header Server=[Apache-Coyote/1.1] as Server 
19:23:56,017 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:88 - Converting org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl -> java.lang.String with value: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl@26d6466f 
19:23:56,018 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:88 - Fallback type converter StaticMethodFallbackTypeConverter: public static java.lang.Object org.apache.camel.component.cxf.converter.CxfConverter.convertTo(java.lang.Class,org.apache.camel.Exchange,java.lang.Object,org.apache.camel.spi.TypeConverterRegistry) converted type from: java.lang.String to: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl 
19:23:56,018 TRACE InstrumentationProcessor:88 - to: Recording duration: 182 millis for exchange: Exchange[Message: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><execution-results><result identifier="message"><org.test.Message><text>echo:Hello World</text></org.test.Message></result><fact-handle identifier="message" external-form="0:2:1391417336:1391417336:2:DEFAULT"/></execution-results>] 
19:23:56,018 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Converting org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl -> java.lang.String with value: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl@26d6466f 
19:23:56,019 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Fallback type converter StaticMethodFallbackTypeConverter: public static java.lang.Object org.apache.camel.component.cxf.converter.CxfConverter.convertTo(java.lang.Class,org.apache.camel.Exchange,java.lang.Object,org.apache.camel.spi.TypeConverterRegistry) converted type from: java.lang.String to: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl 
19:23:56,019 TRACE AsyncProcessorHelper:82 - Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-46148-1384255363195-1-1 -> Exchange[Message: ] 
19:23:56,019 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Converting org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl -> java.lang.String with value: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl@26d6466f 
19:23:56,020 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Fallback type converter StaticMethodFallbackTypeConverter: public static java.lang.Object org.apache.camel.component.cxf.converter.CxfConverter.convertTo(java.lang.Class,org.apache.camel.Exchange,java.lang.Object,org.apache.camel.spi.TypeConverterRegistry) converted type from: java.lang.String to: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl 
19:23:56,020 TRACE AsyncProcessorHelper:82 - Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-46148-1384255363195-1-1 -> Exchange[Message: ] 
19:23:56,020 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Converting org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl -> java.lang.String with value: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl@26d6466f 
19:23:56,021 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Fallback type converter StaticMethodFallbackTypeConverter: public static java.lang.Object org.apache.camel.component.cxf.converter.CxfConverter.convertTo(java.lang.Class,org.apache.camel.Exchange,java.lang.Object,org.apache.camel.spi.TypeConverterRegistry) converted type from: java.lang.String to: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl 
19:23:56,021 TRACE AsyncProcessorHelper:82 - Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-46148-1384255363195-1-1 -> Exchange[Message: ] 
19:23:56,021 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Converting org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl -> java.lang.String with value: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl@26d6466f 
19:23:56,022 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Fallback type converter StaticMethodFallbackTypeConverter: public static java.lang.Object org.apache.camel.component.cxf.converter.CxfConverter.convertTo(java.lang.Class,org.apache.camel.Exchange,java.lang.Object,org.apache.camel.spi.TypeConverterRegistry) converted type from: java.lang.String to: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl 
19:23:56,022 TRACE AsyncProcessorHelper:82 - Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-46148-1384255363195-1-1 -> Exchange[Message: ] 
19:23:56,023 TRACE DefaultErrorHandler:513 - Is exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-46148-1384255363195-1-1 interrupted? false 
19:23:56,023 TRACE DefaultErrorHandler:496 - Is exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-46148-1384255363195-1-1 done? true
19:23:56,023 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Converting org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl -> java.lang.String with value: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl@26d6466f 
19:23:56,023 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Fallback type converter StaticMethodFallbackTypeConverter: public static java.lang.Object org.apache.camel.component.cxf.converter.CxfConverter.convertTo(java.lang.Class,org.apache.camel.Exchange,java.lang.Object,org.apache.camel.spi.TypeConverterRegistry) converted type from: java.lang.String to: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl 
19:23:56,024 TRACE AsyncProcessorHelper:82 - Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-46148-1384255363195-1-1 -> Exchange[Message: ] 
19:23:56,024 TRACE Pipeline:90 - Processing exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-46148-1384255363195-1-1 is continued being processed synchronously 
19:23:56,024 TRACE Pipeline:186 - ExchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-46148-1384255363195-1-1 should continue routing: true 
19:23:56,024 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:113 - Converting org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl -> java.lang.String with value: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl@26d6466f 
19:23:56,025 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:113 - Fallback type converter StaticMethodFallbackTypeConverter: public static java.lang.Object org.apache.camel.component.cxf.converter.CxfConverter.convertTo(java.lang.Class,org.apache.camel.Exchange,java.lang.Object,org.apache.camel.spi.TypeConverterRegistry) converted type from: java.lang.String to: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl 
19:23:56,025 TRACE Pipeline:113 - Processing exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-46148-1384255363195-1-1 >>> Exchange[Message: ] 
19:23:56,025 TRACE BeanProcessor:95 - Using a custom adapter as bean invocation: org.drools.camel.component.PostCxfrs@1a6313e1 
19:23:56,026 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: 
19:23:56,026 TRACE AsyncProcessorHelper:82 - Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-46148-1384255363195-1-1 -> Exchange[Message: ] 
19:23:56,026 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: 
19:23:56,027 TRACE AsyncProcessorHelper:82 - Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-46148-1384255363195-1-1 -> Exchange[Message: ] 
19:23:56,027 TRACE DefaultErrorHandler:513 - Is exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-46148-1384255363195-1-1 interrupted? false 
19:23:56,027 TRACE DefaultErrorHandler:496 - Is exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-46148-1384255363195-1-1 done? true
19:23:56,027 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: 
19:23:56,028 TRACE AsyncProcessorHelper:82 - Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-46148-1384255363195-1-1 -> Exchange[Message: ] 
19:23:56,028 TRACE Pipeline:90 - Processing exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-46148-1384255363195-1-1 is continued being processed synchronously 
19:23:56,028 TRACE Pipeline:186 - ExchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-46148-1384255363195-1-1 should continue routing: false 
19:23:56,028 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:101 - Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: 
19:23:56,028 TRACE Pipeline:101 - Processing complete for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-46148-1384255363195-1-1 >>> Exchange[Message: ] 
19:23:56,029 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: 
19:23:56,029 TRACE AsyncProcessorHelper:82 - Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-46148-1384255363195-1-1 -> Exchange[Message: ] 
19:23:56,029 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: 
19:23:56,029 TRACE AsyncProcessorHelper:82 - Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-46148-1384255363195-1-1 -> Exchange[Message: ] 
19:23:56,030 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: 
19:23:56,030 TRACE AsyncProcessorHelper:82 - Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-46148-1384255363195-1-1 -> Exchange[Message: ] 
19:23:56,030 TRACE DefaultErrorHandler:513 - Is exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-46148-1384255363195-1-1 interrupted? false 
19:23:56,030 TRACE DefaultErrorHandler:496 - Is exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-46148-1384255363195-1-1 done? true
19:23:56,031 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:88 - Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: 
19:23:56,031 TRACE InstrumentationProcessor:88 - route: Recording duration: 200 millis for exchange: Exchange[Message: ] 
19:23:56,031 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:203 - Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: 
19:23:56,031 TRACE DefaultUnitOfWork:203 - UnitOfWork done for ExchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-46148-1384255363195-1-1 with Exchange[Message: ] 
19:23:56,032 TRACE DefaultInflightRepository:58 - Total 0 inflight exchanges. Last removed: ID-icilszxnb126-46148-1384255363195-1-1 
19:23:56,032 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: 
19:23:56,032 TRACE AsyncProcessorHelper:82 - Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-46148-1384255363195-1-1 -> Exchange[Message: ] 
19:23:56,032 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: 
19:23:56,032 TRACE AsyncProcessorHelper:82 - Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-46148-1384255363195-1-1 -> Exchange[Message: ] 
19:23:56,033 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:155 - Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value:
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your attention to my question!

I just fixed this problem

I fix it by set the log level to info in log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout
```

I have set the log level to trace yesterday, I just thought of it maybe the log level cause it.

though the problem is solved, I still cannot understand, why log level will affect the response?

I print some log of the response of two log level

INFO log level

```
11:59:38,174 DEBUG HTTPConduit:1674 - Response Code: 200 Conduit: {http://localhost:8080/drools-camel-server/kservice/rest}WebClient.http-conduit
11:59:38,174 DEBUG HTTPConduit:1675 - Content length: 269
11:59:38,175 DEBUG HTTPConduit:1684 - Header fields: 
    null: [HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
    Date: [Wed, 13 Nov 2013 03:59:38 GMT]
    Content-Length: [269]
    Content-Type: [text/plain]
    Server: [Apache-Coyote/1.1]

11:59:38,176 DEBUG PhaseInterceptorChain:205 - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyInInterceptor@68dd6317 to phase receive
11:59:38,177 DEBUG PhaseInterceptorChain:674 - Chain org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain@31efa79f was created. Current flow:
  receive [PolicyInInterceptor]

11:59:38,178 DEBUG PhaseInterceptorChain:259 - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyInInterceptor@68dd6317
11:59:38,182 DEBUG ConfigurerImpl:405 - Could not determine bean name for instance of class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl.
11:59:38,183 DEBUG ConfigurerImpl:405 - Could not determine bean name for instance of class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyBuilderImpl.
11:59:38,184 DEBUG ConfigurerImpl:405 - Could not determine bean name for instance of class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.ServiceModelPolicyProvider.
11:59:38,185 DEBUG ConfigurerImpl:405 - Could not determine bean name for instance of class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.wsdl11.Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider.
11:59:38,188 DEBUG ConfigurerImpl:405 - Could not determine bean name for instance of class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyInterceptorProviderRegistryImpl.
The response text is <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><execution-results><result identifier="message"><org.test.Message><text>echo: Hello World</text></org.test.Message></result><fact-handle identifier="message" external-form="0:2:2080344259:2080344259:2:DEFAULT"/></execution-results>
```

TRACE log level

```
12:01:29,219 DEBUG HTTPConduit:1674 - Response Code: 200 Conduit: {http://localhost:8080/drools-camel-server/kservice/rest}WebClient.http-conduit
12:01:29,221 DEBUG HTTPConduit:1675 - Content length: 267
12:01:29,222 DEBUG HTTPConduit:1684 - Header fields: 
    null: [HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
    Date: [Wed, 13 Nov 2013 04:01:29 GMT]
    Content-Length: [267]
    Content-Type: [text/plain]
    Server: [Apache-Coyote/1.1]

12:01:29,223 DEBUG PhaseInterceptorChain:205 - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyInInterceptor@31955dd4 to phase receive
12:01:29,224 DEBUG PhaseInterceptorChain:674 - Chain org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain@1f76ed77 was created. Current flow:
  receive [PolicyInInterceptor]

12:01:29,225 DEBUG PhaseInterceptorChain:259 - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyInInterceptor@31955dd4
12:01:29,228 DEBUG ConfigurerImpl:405 - Could not determine bean name for instance of class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl.
12:01:29,229 DEBUG ConfigurerImpl:405 - Could not determine bean name for instance of class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyBuilderImpl.
12:01:29,230 DEBUG ConfigurerImpl:405 - Could not determine bean name for instance of class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.ServiceModelPolicyProvider.
12:01:29,230 DEBUG ConfigurerImpl:405 - Could not determine bean name for instance of class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.wsdl11.Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider.
12:01:29,233 DEBUG ConfigurerImpl:405 - Could not determine bean name for instance of class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyInterceptorProviderRegistryImpl.
12:01:29,236 TRACE CxfRsProducer:183 - Response body = org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl@76ce8e44
12:01:29,237 TRACE DefaultCxfRsBinding:195 - Populate external header Date=[Wed, 13 Nov 2013 04:01:29 GMT] as Date
12:01:29,237 TRACE DefaultCxfRsBinding:195 - Populate external header Content-Length=[267] as Content-Length
12:01:29,237 TRACE DefaultCxfRsBinding:195 - Populate external header Content-Type=[text/plain] as Content-Type
12:01:29,238 TRACE DefaultCxfRsBinding:195 - Populate external header Server=[Apache-Coyote/1.1] as Server
12:01:29,238 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:88 - Converting org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl -> java.lang.String with value: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl@76ce8e44
12:01:29,240 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:88 - Fallback type converter StaticMethodFallbackTypeConverter: public static java.lang.Object org.apache.camel.component.cxf.converter.CxfConverter.convertTo(java.lang.Class,org.apache.camel.Exchange,java.lang.Object,org.apache.camel.spi.TypeConverterRegistry) converted type from: java.lang.String to: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl
12:01:29,240 TRACE InstrumentationProcessor:88 - to: Recording duration: 1318 millis for exchange: Exchange[Message: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><execution-results><result identifier="message"><org.test.Message><text>echo: Hello World</text></org.test.Message></result><fact-handle identifier="message" external-form="0:2:856569878:856569878:2:DEFAULT"/></execution-results>]
12:01:29,241 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Converting org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl -> java.lang.String with value: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl@76ce8e44
12:01:29,242 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Fallback type converter StaticMethodFallbackTypeConverter: public static java.lang.Object org.apache.camel.component.cxf.converter.CxfConverter.convertTo(java.lang.Class,org.apache.camel.Exchange,java.lang.Object,org.apache.camel.spi.TypeConverterRegistry) converted type from: java.lang.String to: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl
12:01:29,242 TRACE AsyncProcessorHelper:82 - Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-42888-1384315286900-0-1 -> Exchange[Message: ]
12:01:29,243 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Converting org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl -> java.lang.String with value: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl@76ce8e44
12:01:29,243 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Fallback type converter StaticMethodFallbackTypeConverter: public static java.lang.Object org.apache.camel.component.cxf.converter.CxfConverter.convertTo(java.lang.Class,org.apache.camel.Exchange,java.lang.Object,org.apache.camel.spi.TypeConverterRegistry) converted type from: java.lang.String to: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl
12:01:29,243 TRACE AsyncProcessorHelper:82 - Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-42888-1384315286900-0-1 -> Exchange[Message: ]
12:01:29,244 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Converting org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl -> java.lang.String with value: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl@76ce8e44
12:01:29,244 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Fallback type converter StaticMethodFallbackTypeConverter: public static java.lang.Object org.apache.camel.component.cxf.converter.CxfConverter.convertTo(java.lang.Class,org.apache.camel.Exchange,java.lang.Object,org.apache.camel.spi.TypeConverterRegistry) converted type from: java.lang.String to: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl
12:01:29,244 TRACE AsyncProcessorHelper:82 - Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-42888-1384315286900-0-1 -> Exchange[Message: ]
12:01:29,245 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Converting org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl -> java.lang.String with value: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl@76ce8e44
12:01:29,245 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Fallback type converter StaticMethodFallbackTypeConverter: public static java.lang.Object org.apache.camel.component.cxf.converter.CxfConverter.convertTo(java.lang.Class,org.apache.camel.Exchange,java.lang.Object,org.apache.camel.spi.TypeConverterRegistry) converted type from: java.lang.String to: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl
12:01:29,245 TRACE AsyncProcessorHelper:82 - Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-42888-1384315286900-0-1 -> Exchange[Message: ]
12:01:29,246 TRACE DefaultErrorHandler:513 - Is exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-42888-1384315286900-0-1 interrupted? false
12:01:29,246 TRACE DefaultErrorHandler:496 - Is exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-42888-1384315286900-0-1 done? true
12:01:29,246 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Converting org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl -> java.lang.String with value: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl@76ce8e44
12:01:29,247 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Fallback type converter StaticMethodFallbackTypeConverter: public static java.lang.Object org.apache.camel.component.cxf.converter.CxfConverter.convertTo(java.lang.Class,org.apache.camel.Exchange,java.lang.Object,org.apache.camel.spi.TypeConverterRegistry) converted type from: java.lang.String to: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl
12:01:29,247 TRACE AsyncProcessorHelper:82 - Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-42888-1384315286900-0-1 -> Exchange[Message: ]
12:01:29,247 TRACE Pipeline:90 - Processing exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-42888-1384315286900-0-1 is continued being processed synchronously
12:01:29,247 TRACE Pipeline:186 - ExchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-42888-1384315286900-0-1 should continue routing: true
12:01:29,248 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:113 - Converting org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl -> java.lang.String with value: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl@76ce8e44
12:01:29,248 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:113 - Fallback type converter StaticMethodFallbackTypeConverter: public static java.lang.Object org.apache.camel.component.cxf.converter.CxfConverter.convertTo(java.lang.Class,org.apache.camel.Exchange,java.lang.Object,org.apache.camel.spi.TypeConverterRegistry) converted type from: java.lang.String to: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl
12:01:29,248 TRACE Pipeline:113 - Processing exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-42888-1384315286900-0-1 >>> Exchange[Message: ]
12:01:29,249 TRACE BeanProcessor:95 - Using a custom adapter as bean invocation: org.drools.camel.component.PostCxfrs@7d76a8c8
12:01:29,255 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: 
12:01:29,255 TRACE AsyncProcessorHelper:82 - Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-42888-1384315286900-0-1 -> Exchange[Message: ]
12:01:29,255 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: 
12:01:29,256 TRACE AsyncProcessorHelper:82 - Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-42888-1384315286900-0-1 -> Exchange[Message: ]
12:01:29,256 TRACE DefaultErrorHandler:513 - Is exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-42888-1384315286900-0-1 interrupted? false
12:01:29,256 TRACE DefaultErrorHandler:496 - Is exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-42888-1384315286900-0-1 done? true
12:01:29,257 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: 
12:01:29,257 TRACE AsyncProcessorHelper:82 - Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-42888-1384315286900-0-1 -> Exchange[Message: ]
12:01:29,257 TRACE Pipeline:90 - Processing exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-42888-1384315286900-0-1 is continued being processed synchronously
12:01:29,258 TRACE Pipeline:186 - ExchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-42888-1384315286900-0-1 should continue routing: false
12:01:29,258 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:101 - Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: 
12:01:29,258 TRACE Pipeline:101 - Processing complete for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-42888-1384315286900-0-1 >>> Exchange[Message: ]
12:01:29,259 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: 
12:01:29,259 TRACE AsyncProcessorHelper:82 - Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-42888-1384315286900-0-1 -> Exchange[Message: ]
12:01:29,259 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: 
12:01:29,259 TRACE AsyncProcessorHelper:82 - Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-42888-1384315286900-0-1 -> Exchange[Message: ]
12:01:29,260 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: 
12:01:29,260 TRACE AsyncProcessorHelper:82 - Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-42888-1384315286900-0-1 -> Exchange[Message: ]
12:01:29,260 TRACE DefaultErrorHandler:513 - Is exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-42888-1384315286900-0-1 interrupted? false
12:01:29,260 TRACE DefaultErrorHandler:496 - Is exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-42888-1384315286900-0-1 done? true
12:01:29,261 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:88 - Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: 
12:01:29,261 TRACE InstrumentationProcessor:88 - route: Recording duration: 1352 millis for exchange: Exchange[Message: ]
12:01:29,261 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:203 - Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: 
12:01:29,262 TRACE DefaultUnitOfWork:203 - UnitOfWork done for ExchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-42888-1384315286900-0-1 with Exchange[Message: ]
12:01:29,263 TRACE DefaultInflightRepository:58 - Total 0 inflight exchanges. Last removed: ID-icilszxnb126-42888-1384315286900-0-1
12:01:29,263 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: 
12:01:29,263 TRACE AsyncProcessorHelper:82 - Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-42888-1384315286900-0-1 -> Exchange[Message: ]
12:01:29,264 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:82 - Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: 
12:01:29,264 TRACE AsyncProcessorHelper:82 - Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-icilszxnb126-42888-1384315286900-0-1 -> Exchange[Message: ]
12:01:29,264 TRACE DefaultTypeConverter:155 - Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: 
The response text is
```